# Are questions about modifying hardware on topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

If you read the question title, the question is pretty obvious....**are questions about modifying the hardware of Android devices on-topic on this site?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say not.  Hardware modding doesn't really have anything to do with Android the platform, and would generally be generically about cell hardware than specifically Android hardware.  It also doesn't match the expertise of most of our users.

From its topic description, [the Electrical Engineering SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) might be host to a subset of such questions.

Comment: Agreed. Speaking in terms of our help-center: *expressly off-topic here: […] Android-independent questions*, as you've just described :)

Comment: Fair enough....figured I'd ask here before asking on the main site....didn't see this before, but [this question](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/1003/65853) from the related questions on the side of this page caught my eye......says pretty much the same as you did. Thanks.